# How to add merge modules (.msm) to an Install Script using Install shield application?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript, merge-module, installshield-2011

I am using Install Shield and I know that we can add the merge modules using the `Redistributables` menu item if it was a `Basic MSI Project`.

But I do not see the `Redistributables` menu item if it was `InstallScript Project`

Can some one help me out in figuring how to add merge modules if to an InstallScript Project using Install Shield ?

Answer (score 2):

See the help topic: [Adding Merge Modules and Objects to InstallScript Projects](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/AddingRedistsInstallScript.htm)

AFAIK, InstallShield creates an MSI it calls the "merge module holder object".  So basically a dummy MSI is created to contain the merge module's components and then it gets called by the InstallScript project.

IOW, I wouldn't want to do this. :)

Comment: To expand on this slightly, the merge module holder object is an .msi file you don't have full control over, launched automatically by the object. So my recommendation is to do similar steps explicitly so you do (i.e. create your own .msi separately, launch it for install or uninstall with LaunchApplication, etc.) Or, as applicable, find a better redistributable for your purpose, and call it instead.